# How to use a global variable to update a selection field with Odoo 10?

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables, odoo, odoo-10

Hi is it possible to have a global variable which gets updated based on 'onchange' and assign the same to a selection field?

```
variable = []

class a:
    @api.onchange('some_other_filed')
    def function1(self):
        global variable
        variable = #something based on some other filed

    test = fields.Selection(variable)
```

Will this onchange reflect in selection field. All I get is empty list in selection field.

Comment: @Naveen Not yet bro. I created a temporary table and used Many2one field instead of Selection field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using global variables is not recommended. You can use a persistent field on the `ir.config_parameter` table if you want to make it always available from anywhere in Odoo. You can see the stored configuration parameters on **Settings > Technical > Parameters > System Parameters**.

You can set the value of the parameter like this:

```
self.env['ir.config_parameter'].set_param('use_journal_setting', True)
```

And get some other value like this:

```
location = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param(
    'ir_attachment.location'
)
```

You can also update the selection field directly with some value, or you can use the parameter to update it.

```
@api.onchange('field_name')
def onchange_field_name(self):
    self.test = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('parameter_name')
```

**Note**: If you need many of these global variables, consider creating your own parameters table.